# Does this product page contradict the corresponding datasheet?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, datasheet, breadboard

I'm currently using N-channel MOSFET's my hobby circuit, and have had two go out on me. As a result, I'm studying them a little more and making sure I'm not doing anything that might harm them.

On [this product page](https://www.adafruit.com/products/355), the description of the item says

"The threshhold voltage is also very low, less than 2.5V so you can control it directly from a microcontroller running on 2.8V, 3.3V or 5V logic."

However, on [the datasheet](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/irlb8721pbf.pdf), V_gs(th) is listed as 1.35V min, 2.35V max.

Am I interpreting the data sheet correctly? If not, what exactly does this rating represent?

Comment: Your MOSFETs may be dying due to static issues, or forgetting the bypass diode on a motor driver.

Comment: @pjc50, you're right; I'm using an LED for the bypass diode, and it appears to be lighting up the mosfet is turned off, so that's good. I only have two and I've messed around with them so much there could be a number of things I've done to them. A multimeter diode clearly shows that both are either duds or broken. I have a pack of 10 coming that I'll be more careful with!

Answer (score 4):

The two descriptions do not contradict each other, but some explanation of Vgs(th) may be useful.

- Vgs(th) of MOSFET devices is the voltage at its Gate, at which **the device barely begins to switch on** - this is not the voltage to drive the Gate at, if the device is to be used in its fully conducting, therefore low dissipation "on" mode.
- The "fully effective" Vgs voltage for a low Rds(on) is much higher, and is often not explicitly mentioned in many MOSFET datasheets. Note that this particular datasheet states "*Very Low RDS(on) at **4.5V** VGS*", so that should be the **minimum** gate drive voltage to aim for.
- The minimum and maximum Vgs(th) ratings reflect the fact that there is often a **large variation in threshold voltage** of MOSFETs in manufacturing, even within parts from the same batch. The range indicates the best case and worst case Gate voltage for a given product, at which the device barely begins to conduct. This "maximum" is not the maximum voltage that can and should be applied to the Gate.
- The maximum Vgs the part can tolerate is separately listed in the Absolute Maximum Ratings, **± 20 Volts** for this datasheet.

MOSFET datasheets are often confusing for this reason, that the ratings provided do not highlight what voltage range is ideal to drive the gate at: "Vgs for good conduction: 4.5 Volts to 20 Volts" would have been a very useful line for this datasheet, for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that for me. It makes perfect sense now.